# eclipse sonar c project

Tags: c, eclipse, sonarqube

I have a `C` embedded project. I can run a sonar analysis thanks to `sonar-runner`. In eclipse I add sonar nature to my project. But when I want run a local analysis, I have this message :
Language with key 'cpp' not found.

When I watch project properties, in sonar group, the language is forced to cpp and I cannot change it ... An idea to change it ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Sonar Eclipse is not compatible with C projects (only C++), as you can see on the [compatibility matrix of the install page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse).

Obviously, we'll work on that so that C projects are supported.